# Occasional "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed" connecting to DigitalOcean Managed Database

Tags: php, mysql, digital-ocean, litespeed

The other day I purchased a DigitalOcean Managed Database to use as a secondary MySQL server to reduce load on our primary CPanel CentOS server.

This has worked great but every couple of hours our error logs from our PHP scripts fill with the following errors:

```
[24-Jan-2022 04:16:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known 
[24-Jan-2022 04:16:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known 
[24-Jan-2022 04:16:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_set_charset(): Couldn't fetch mysqli
[24-Jan-2022 04:16:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli
[24-Jan-2022 04:16:21 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on null
```

These errors are originating on this line:

```
$db = new mysqli("ygo-external-database-do-user-10645539-0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com:25060","username","password", "database");
```

I don't think it's a firewall issue since it is working most of the time. The website is also using `Cloudflare` but I don't think that is the issue either as I paused Cloudflare once when it occurred and the issue remained for ~20 minutes or so. Restarting the `Litespeed` web server tends to fix this immediately but I am non the wiser as to why this is happening.

Comment: Try reading error logs on server, since this error means that `ygo-external-database-do-user-10645539-0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com:25060` does not exists

Comment: @Justinas You can't access the logs directly on a DigitalOcean Managed Database instance. However, on the dashboard under "recent log entries" there are no entires for the 24th January. Reference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/can-i-access-database-mysql-logs

Comment: So maybe contact DigitalOcean for support?

Comment: Sure. I wanted to check if anyone has come across it here first....